# Where can I find the discovery feature documentation for GetStream.io

Tags: getstream-io

I started working with GetStream, and I am looking to implement a **discovery** or **suggestion** feature, but I cannot find documentation for the feature in GetStream.

https://getstream.io/personalization

Anyone know a good source that I can start with

Comment: There is a form to request access to the personalization APIs at the bottom of this page: https://getstream.io/personalization